# How do I disable the screen lock requirement in Boxen?

Tags: boxen

I'm using Boxen to configure several virtual machine build agents. Because these machines' host computer is password protected, I want to use automatic login and disable screen lock in these virtual machines' Boxen configuration.

By default, Boxen seems to reset the password screen lock timeout to 5 seconds whenever run. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Password screenlock out is from this boxen code:

```
class boxen::security(
  $require_password = true,
  $screensaver_delay_sec = 5
) {
  boxen::osx_defaults { 'require password at screensaver':
    ensure => present,
    domain => 'com.apple.screensaver',
    key    => 'askForPassword',
    value  => $require_password,
    type   => 'bool',
    user   => $::boxen_user
  }

  boxen::osx_defaults { 'short delay for password dialog on screensaver':
    ensure => present,
    domain => 'com.apple.screensaver',
    key    => 'askForPasswordDelay',
    value  => $screensaver_delay_sec,
    type   => 'float',
    user   => $::boxen_user
  }
}
```

So you should be able to remove it by adding this to your boxen setup:

```
class { 'boxen::security':
  require_password => false,
}
```